# React routing interferes with Express endpoints

Tags: javascript, reactjs, proxy, react-router

I created a proxy to Express server, it used to work before, now it makes a request to server when I try to go on another route. For example, I have `/posts` server endpoint and `/posts` route.

Here is my server file:

```js
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const passport = require("passport");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const path = require('path');
dotenv.config({ silent: true });


const app = express();

// database connection
require('./config/database');

// bodyparser, cors setup
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

// passport setup
app.use(passport.initialize());
require("./config/passport.js")(passport);

app.use(morgan("dev"));


// static
app.use('/uploads', express.static(__dirname + '/static/uploads'))

// routes 
app.use("/api/posts", require('./routes/posts'));
app.use("/api/comments", require('./routes/comments'));
app.use("/api/auth", require('./routes/user'));




app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  res.status(err.code || 500).send({ error: err.message || 'Internal server error happened' })
})



const PORT = 5000 || process.env.PORT;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`App running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

I tried with adding static file but doesn't work. Probably I would need it in production.

Here is the package.json proxy setup: 
`"proxy": "http://localhost:5000/api/"`

Comment: Is react app created with create-react-app or with your own webpack configuration?

Comment: Create-react-app, I also tried to recreate it, deleted all setup files, node modules and the rest